# Spring data elasticsearch named queries for agreggation

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have query with large aggregation and because of that, I'm trying to use named queries for elasticsearch. I managed to read the query from the properties file but I'm unable to read aggregation. Is there a way to read the entire query and queries aggregation from the properties file?

**Working example of reading query:**

**QueryRepository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends ExtendedElasticsearchRepository<User, Integer> {
    //named query lookup found getUserQuery inside users-named-queries.properties and used its query
    SearchHits<User> getUserQuery(Integer fieldId);
}
```

**Method call:**

```
SearchHits<User> users = userRepository.getUserQuery(1); <- returns hits
Aggregations usersAggregations = users.getAggregations(); <- returns null beacouse there is no aggregation
```

**App:**

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org...", repositoryBaseClass = CdpElasticsearchRepository.class, namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:*-named-queries.properties")
```

**users-named-queries.properties**

```
User.getUserQuery={"bool": { "filter": [{"term": {"fieldId": ?0}}]}}
```

**Desirable behavior:**

```
User.getUserQuery={"query":{"bool": { "filter": [{"term": {"fieldId": ?0}}]}}, "aggs": {"sum_field": {"sum": {"field": "fieldId"}}}}
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException:
> Elasticsearch exception [type=parsing_exception, reason=unknown query
> [query]]; nested exception is
> ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=parsing_exception, reason=unknown query [query]]]; nested:
> ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=named_object_not_found_exception, reason=[1:10] unknown field
> [query]]];

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about the `namedQueriesLocation` property. This was added by the original author of Spring Data Elasticsearch back in 2013 and it seems not to be used in the whole project. What do you mean with _"I managed to read the query from the properties file"_? And where is `userRepository.getUserQuery(1);`implemented?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch added some other information to clear things us. There is no other implementation, that's it, query inside properties file fetched via name and when called it's executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I learned something about Spring Data Elasticsearch which I did not yet know: You can define queries in a queries properties file as an alternative to use `@Query` annotated functions. Thanks for pushing me into that.

These queries are the same as when using the `@Query` annotation and this means that only the *query* part of a search request sent to Elasticsearch can be put in there, not the *aggs* or what else might go into the body of a search request.

The value of the named query is sent to Elasticsearch in a [wrapper query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html) which will only take the query part and not *aggs*.

I agree that it would be great to be able to add aggs or other elements, I created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2062) for that,.

Comment: Nice, looking forward to this feature